# Powershell diff and lookup values

Tags: powershell, foreach

My code compares md5 values - I have a bit where I should only be getting the ones that are in the difference var ... hence the sidecar indicator bit. Two questions:

1. how do I get the ones that are only true
2. Maybe more to the point I need to get the md5's where its true AND then use those values to filter another variable which stores the file paths ($remotefiles - has both the md5 and the paths)

```
    $diffmd5 = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $localmd5 -DifferenceObject $remotemd5 -IncludeEqual | ForEach-Object {($_.SideIndicator -eq '=>')}
```

Comment: try replacing the `ForEach-Object` at the end with `Where-Object`. [*grin*]

Comment: Mm yes that solves the first problem - now I guess I gotta do the lookup bit

Comment: kool! glad to have helped ... you may want to make the 2nd part a new Question. it's generally considered counterproductive to ask a multi-part Question. [*grin*]